# Jenkins pipeline-stage-view does not show nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The stage view of my jenkins jobs does not show the names of the nodes where the stages are executed on.

I'm running:

- Jenkins ver. 1.642.4.2 (CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise 15.11)
- build-pipeline-plugin - 1.5.3.1
- pipeline-stage-view - 2.0

one stage of my pipeline skript:

```
node (SLAVE){
try{
    //  Stage 1: FLOW Settings 
    stage 'FLOW Settings'
    bat '''@echo off && %WORKSPACE_PATH%__TM_python\\python.exe %WORKSPACE_PATH%__TM_source\\FlowSettings.py ''' + jsonString
    currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
}catch(Exception err) {}
```

Comment: In the [pipeline-stage-view release notes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin) is mentioned that in version 1.5 they removed node labels: _REMOVE node labels in stage view (per JENKINS-34038) until we can correctly handle more of the cases with a block-based pipeline graph analysis_

Comment: i thought it would be possible again, because the issue was set to fixed and implemented in version 2.0 [link](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34038)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing StageView, [Blue Ocean](https://jenkins.io//projects/blueocean/) was created as a new UI for Jenkins. Node names are more likely to appear in Blue Ocean then in StageView.